# Is XChaCha20-Poly1305 nonce misuse-resistant?

Tags: nonce, chacha, misuse-resistant

In the [Libsodium v1.0.12 and v1.0.13 Security Assessment](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/blog/2017/08/libsodium-v1-0-12-and-v1-0-13-security-assessment/) one can read

> The ChaCha20-Poly1305 implementation combines a stream cipher and is
>   resistant to timing attacks by design. In addition, this particular
>   construction has two additional variants implemented in libsodium: an
>   IETF version [7] and one with an extended nonce (XChaCha20-Poly1305)
>   [4]. One benefit of the XChaCha20Poly1305 construction is that it
>   enables nonce misuse-resistant schemes.

However, I don't understand how XChaCha20-Poly1305 construction is nonce misuse-resistant.

From my understanding, XChaCha20 works as follows:

1. Generates a 192-bit random nonce (6 32-bit words $nonce_0,...,nonce_5$)
2. Build the initial block $B \leftarrow
   \begin{matrix}
   c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3\\
   k_0 & k_1 & k_2 &k_3\\
   k_4 & k_5 & k_6 &k_7\\
   nonce_0 & nonce_1 & nonce_2 & nonce_3
   \end{matrix}$ where $c_i$ are constants and $k_i$ are key words
3. Runs ChaCha without the final block addition $B' \leftarrow \mathtt{HChaCha20}(B)$
4. Build the subblock $B'' \leftarrow
   \begin{matrix}
   c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3\\
   B'_0 & B'_1 & B'_2 &B'_3\\
   B'_{12} & B'_{13} & B'_{14} &B'_{15}\\
   counter_0 & counter_1 & nonce_4 & nonce_5
   \end{matrix}$
5. Runs ChaCha20 using $B''$.

In this way, using the same nonce will output the same keystream.
However, as I understand, nonce-misuse resistance schemes ensure that a repeated random nonce doesn't result in plaintext compromise.

So it seems that when using XChaCha20-Poly1305 with random nonce, one can ensure that the probablity of a repeated nonce is negligible. But this is not the definition of a nonce miseuse-resistant scheme.

**How to build a nonce misuse-resistant schemes using XChaCha20Poly1305?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation on [libsodium AEAD constructions](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead.html) provides more details.

Namely, it lists `Hk(random ‖ m)` as a way to compute a synthetic XChaCha20 nonce. Even if `random` is not unique, the nonce is unlikely to be the same for different messages.

Even more relevant are the sections on [nonce-misuse resistance](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/encrypted-messages.html#nonce-misuse-resistance) and [short nonces](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/encrypted-messages.html#short-nonces).

Note that like all other nonce-misuse resistance schemes, this requires two passes over the data.

Comment: isn't this dangerous? Because of length-extension, if one encrypt `m` and `m || pad || something` with the same nonce (let's say by mistake). Then an observer who can guess `something` can detect that `X || pad || something` has been encrypted.

Comment: if we play the game proof: In the beginning I ask you for the encryption of `m`. After I send you `rand_msg` and `m || pad || something`, you send me the encryption of one of them, I can tell which one.

Comment: Note the requirement for the synthetic nonce: a keyed hash function. This suggests HMAC, which is immune to length extension attacks. In the context of the libsodium documentation, this refers to either the HMAC construction, or BLAKE2, which is also resistant against length extension attacks.